# From Swift how to get multibles Arrays from PHP

Tags: php, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I have this in my PHP file:

```
$test1 = array("id" => "1222","name" => "Sami");

$test2 = array("id" => "555","name" => "Mark");

$tt = array();

array_push($tt, $test1, $test2);


echo json_encode($tt);
```

Now I want to get this data from swift, I tried this:

```
var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
teamJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

But, it doesn't works! teamJSON = Nil , how to present this data , any help?

Comment: 1. Your data is an array, not a dictionary. 2. Don't use `NSDictionary` (or `NSArray`) in Swift, use native (Swift) arrays and dictionaries. 3. And then using `.mutableContainers` is pointless.

Comment: but when I use echo json_encode($test1); nested ($tt) my code is works using Dictionary!!?